# Python socket sendall blocks and I'm not sure how to handle bad clients / slow consumers

Tags: python, sockets

To simplify things, assume a TCP client-server app where the client sends a request and the server responds. The server uses sendall to respond to each client.

Now assume a bad client that sends requests to the server but doesn't really handle the responses. I.e. the client never calls socket.recv. (It doesn't have to be a bad client btw...it may be a slow consumer on the other end).

What ends up happening, is that the server keeps sending responses using sendall, until I'm assuming a buffer gets full, and then at some point sendall blocks and never returns.

This seems like a common problem to me so what would be the recommended solution?
Is there something like a try-send that would raise or return an EWOULDBLOCK (or similar) if the recipient's buffer is full? I'd like to avoid non-blocking select type calls if possible (happy to go that way if there are no alternatives).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can set a timeout for the socket operation. Drop the client when a timeout occurs.

Comment: Notice how the function you're using is called send**all**? If you don't want to send all, then...

Comment: I do want to sendall...I want to sendall 99% of the cases. But I don't want the server to suffer due to a bad client/slow consumer. rveerd, what you're proposing sounds sensible. How do I do this? In terms of flags the only relevant one I can see is MSG_DONTWAIT, which is not the same thing...

Comment: rveerd, thank you for the suggestion. I'm looking at settimeout and setdefaulttimeout. I think this will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Following rveed's comment, here's a solution that works for my case:

```
def send_to_socket(self, sock: socket.socket, message: bytes) -> bool:
    try:
        sock.settimeout(10.0) # protect against bad clients / slow consumers by making this timeout (instead of blocking)
        res = sock.sendall(message)
        sock.settimeout(None) # put back to blocking (if needed for subsequent calls to recv, etc. using this socket)
        if res is not None:
            return False

        return True

        except socket.timeout as st:
            # do whatever you need to here
            return False

        except Exception as ex:
            # handle other exceptions here
            return False
```

If needed, instead of setting the timeout to None afterwards (i.e. back to blocking), you can store the previous timeout value (using gettimeout) and restore to that.